# Dinamic case match in Scala based on fixed elements in a list

Tags: scala

Assume I have a List of possibles *Credit Card*

```
val availableCreditsCard = List(MasterCardCreditCard, VisaCreditCard)
```

Both those classes extends a trait called `CreditCard`

Now, I want to create a method, called `isValid` that accept the trait `CreditCard`

Something like:

```
  def isValid(creditCard: CreditCard): Boolean = {
    creditCard match {
      case t: MasterCardCreditCard => MasterCardCreditCardPayment.isValid(t)
      case s: VisaCreditCard => VisaCreditCardPayment.isValid(s)
    }
  }
```

Both *MasterCardCreditCardPayment* and *VisaCreditCardPayment* extends a trait called `CreditCardPayment`.

So, now, my question is, what if I want to add a new possible CreditCard (Amex), with his own CreditCardPayment (AmexCreditCardPayment), but just change the list `availableCreditsCard` and doesn't touch the *match/case* inside the isValid method?

Is it possible to create dinamically this match/case based on the list `availableCreditsCard`?

**EDIT**

This is the CreditCardPayment trait.

```
trait CreditCardPayment[CreditCard] {
  def isValid(creditCard: CreditCard): Boolean
  def checkCVV(creditCard: CreditCard): Boolean
}
```

and an example of `VisaCreditCardPayment`

```
object VisaCreditCardPayment extends CreditCardPayment[VisaCreditCard] {

  override def isValid(creditCard: VisaCreditCard): Boolean = {
    val listValidCreditCard = loadFile()
    listValidCreditCard.contains(creditCard)
  }

  //Implemented because it the trait, not necessary
  override def checkCVV(creditCard: VisaCreditCard): Boolean = {
    val listCreditCard = loadFile()
    val cvvToCheck = creditCard.cvv
    listCreditCard.exists(_.cvv == cvvToCheck)
  }
}
```

Now, your suggestion is, inside the `isValid` method, use a `case t => CreditCardPayment.isValid(t)`. This is not even actual possible, since `CreditCardPayment` is a trait :(

Comment: If you are changing the requirement I think you will have to change the code too and you should to avoid any bug.

Comment: Yup, I'm completely agree with this, and thinking by myself, I was like, well, yeah, If I add a new type of payments, I should change the code itself to be extra sure that everything is going to work properly, but still, do you think this is possible in any way?

Comment: Just make `.isValid` a method on `CreditCard`. Then you can just do `creditCard.isValid()` without any auxiliary code to keep in synch.

Comment: If you want to perform some common functionality on all the other type of cards you can write _ case in your match case.

Comment: @Dima I think he is not looking to access isValid method from CreditCard he want to use the implementation of isValid on the new type of CreditCard without any change in match case.

Comment: @RamanMishra I couldn't since `CreditCardPayment` is typed, so VisaCreditCardPayment can accept ONLY VisaCreditCard

Comment: Why can’t you as @Dima is suggesting that define cardPayment method in CardPayment trait and it will be available for all payment type instance.

Comment: @RamanMishra Because simply I cannot do it. `CreditCardPayment` is a trait, that define just the isValid. Since `isValid` could (and should) change from each Circuit (Mastercard has a different `API` than Visa) I cannot even implement it on the trait itself

Comment: @AntonioCalì you don't _implement_ it on the trait, just _declare_ it there. Then implement for each subclass.

Comment: @Dima but I've already done it. I posted the code for show this. I've just defined the isValid in trait, and implemented in each class that extend the `CreditCardPayment` trait.

Comment: @Tizianoreica wrong trait. I am talking about `CreditCard`

Comment: Ok I now recognize that there actually things a little bit confusing in my explanations. The `isValid` method I'm trying to implement via the match/case DOES NOT have any in common with `CreditCardPayment isValid` Method. I just want to create a "PaymentSystem" that accept any valid CreditCard that I declared possible in the list `availableCreditsCard`, and in case of a recognisible creditCard, use hiw own `CreditCardPayment` instance (Like, If I have a Visa I want to use VisaCreditCardPayment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it "dynamic", just use inheritance rather than implementing it "on the side":

```
   sealed trait CreditCard {
      def isValid: Boolean
   }

   class MasterCard extends CreditCard {
      def isValid = MasterCardCreditCardPayment.isValid(this)
   }
   class Visa extends CreditCard {
      def isValid = VisaCreditCardPayment.isValid(this)
   }
```

Now, you can just do `def isValid(c: CreditCard) = c.isValid`, no need for any `match` statements to keep in sync.

And when you add Amex:

```
   class Amex extends CreditCard {
       def isValid = AmexCreditCardPayment.isValid(this)
   }
```

The `isValid(amex)` will just work, nothing needs to be updated.

Comment: Is this pretty much a "Visitor" Design Pattern, right? Great idea, btw

Comment: @Tizianoreica I have no idea what that "visitor" thing is :) Back in my days, this was just called encapsulation :D

Answer (score 1):

Complementing Dima's answer. Since, you always want to delegate the `isValid` logic to the appropriate `Payment`. I will present you two ways to do not redefine the method in each sub-class.

One method using **F-Bounded Polymorphism**, which will require quite a boilerplate code for each sub-class, and it is not completely *typesafe* - thus may not worth the work.
And the second using **typeclasses**, which will be more *typesafe*, and will require less boilerplate for each new card.
For a more detailed discussion about **F-Bounded** vs **Typeclasses**, read [this](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) article.

#### Using F-Bounded

```
sealed trait CreditCardPayment[CC <: CreditCard[CC]] {
  def isValid(creditCard: CC): Boolean
  def checkCVV(creditCard: CC): Boolean
}

object VisaCreditCardPayment extends CreditCardPayment[VisaCreditCard] {
  private final val validCreditCards: List[VisaCreditCard] = ???

  override def isValid(creditCard: VisaCreditCard): Boolean =
    validCreditCards.contains(creditCard)

  override def checkCVV(creditCard: VisaCreditCard): Boolean =
    validCreditCards.exists(_.cvv == creditCard.cvv)
}

object MasterCreditCardPayment extends CreditCardPayment[MasterCreditCard] {
  private final val validCreditCards: List[MasterCreditCard] = ???

  override def isValid(creditCard: MasterCreditCard): Boolean =
    validCreditCards.contains(creditCard)

  override def checkCVV(creditCard: MasterCreditCard): Boolean =
    validCreditCards.exists(_.cvv == creditCard.cvv)
}

sealed trait CreditCard[CC <: CreditCard[CC]] { self: CC =>
  def paymentMethod: CreditCardPayment[CC]

  def cvv: String

  final def isValid: Boolean =
    paymentMethod.isValid(this)
}

final class VisaCreditCard (override val cvv: String) extends CreditCard[VisaCreditCard] {
  override final val paymentMethod: CreditCardPayment[VisaCreditCard] = VisaCreditCardPayment
}

final class MasterCreditCard (override val cvv: String) extends CreditCard[MasterCreditCard] {
  override final val paymentMethod: CreditCardPayment[MasterCreditCard] = MasterCreditCardPayment
}
```

#### Using Typeclasses

```
sealed trait CreditCardPayment[CC <: CreditCard] {
  def isValid(creditCard: CC): Boolean
  def checkCVV(creditCard: CC): Boolean
}

sealed trait CreditCard {
  def cvv: String
}

// Provides the 'isValid' & 'checkCVV' extension methods to any CredictCard.
implicit class CreditCardOps[CC <: CreditCard](val self: CC) extends AnyVal {
  def isValid(implicit payment: CreditCardPayment[CC]): Boolean =
    payment.isValid(self)

  def checkCVV(implicit payment: CreditCardPayment[CC]): Boolean =
    payment.checkCVV(self)
}

final class VisaCreditCard (override val cvv: String) extends CreditCard

object VisaCreditCard {
    final implicit val VisaCreditCardPayment: CreditCardPayment[VisaCreditCard] = new CreditCardPayment[VisaCreditCard] {
      final val validCreditCards: List[VisaCreditCard] = ???

      override def isValid(creditCard: VisaCreditCard): Boolean =
        validCreditCards.contains(creditCard)

      override def checkCVV(creditCard: VisaCreditCard): Boolean =
        validCreditCards.exists(_.cvv == creditCard.cvv)
    }
}

final class MasterCreditCard (override val cvv: String) extends CreditCard

object MasterCreditCard {
  final implicit val MasterCreditCardPayment: CreditCardPayment[MasterCreditCard] = new CreditCardPayment[MasterCreditCard] {
    final val validCreditCards: List[MasterCreditCard] = ???

    override def isValid(creditCard: MasterCreditCard): Boolean =
      validCreditCards.contains(creditCard)

    override def checkCVV(creditCard: MasterCreditCard): Boolean =
      validCreditCards.exists(_.cvv == creditCard.cvv)
  }
}
```

Using the **typeclass** approach you can also define the `isValid` method for `CreditCards` as a function instead.
*(This way you do not need to define and import the `CreditCardOps` implicit / value class)*.

```
def isValid[CC <: CreditCard](cc: CC)(implicit payment: CreditCardPayment[CC]): Boolean =
  payment.isValid(cc)
```